# Not to forget something or ...?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

How do we say correctly the following?

> For not to forget about it he wrote a reminder to his agenda.

`for not to forget` sounds strange, what is the correct way to say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of possibilities, including the following:

> So as not to forget (about it)
>   In order not to forget (about it)
>   To remind himself (about it)
>   To remember/recall/recollect

But **for not to forget** is NOT colloquial, as you note.